# How to get a user name by its id in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-admin

I have models `User` and `Article`.

`User` has the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
```

and `Article`'s:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, required: true
```

I use *rails_admin* as a control panel and customize a required fields in `rails_admin.rb` as follows:

```
  config.model Article do
    list do
      field :id
      field :title
      field :user_id
      field :created_at
    end
  end
```

But how to implement that instead of `:user_id` displays the name of the user? I have a `username` field in my database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Article` model, you can add a custom method that will return the `user_name`:

```
def user_name
  self.user.username
end
```

Then, you can use this `user_name` field in your admin like other model attributes:

```
config.model Article do
  list do
    field :id
    field :title
    field :created_at
    field :user_name
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I get the following error: **undefined method `object_label_method'**

Comment: can you try just: `field :user_name` without that `object_label_method` see if that works?If not, let me know. for `object_label_method ` we need some more configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another stab at it...

Rails_admin looks for a "name" or "title" field on the model, if there are none, it will display a somewhat ugly "User#1".

All you need to do in your User Model is to add the following method:

```
def title
  try(:username)
end
```

I like to go back to this presentation for Rails Admin's best practices: http://www.slideshare.net/benoitbenezech/rails-admin-overbest-practices

It's a bit dated but everything you need is there (around page 14 for your case)